# Is there any module to add seasonal discount in ODOO?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Is there any module to add seasonal discount in ODOO?
For example I want to make discount from Dec 25th (Christmas) to Jan 1st(New Year).
Help me with any idea or suggest me any module which is already available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Pricelist in odoo8. In Pricelist, you can create Pricelist Versions with your seasonal dates. In Versions, you can create Price List Items with discount, with Product categories/Products for which it should be apply. By configuring Pricelist in such way, you can get your things done.

Comment: For Pricelist, we need to add product in that list. I want to create discount for all the product in even manner.

Comment: Product, Template and Category are not required fields to define Price List Items so if you will not set any value in these fields, it will apply to all products. You can test it and let me know.

Comment: Thank you, Let me try this.